# Android JSON parsing: parse a particular element

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have a mentioned bellow could you let me know how to parse only Tripname in this json

I want like

delta
Baby
bluebay
whaynle

from the json

```
MyJson 

[{"0":"$deta","Tripname":"delta"},{"0":"Baby","Tripname":"Baby"},{"0":"bluebay","Tripname":"bluebay"},{"0":"whaynle","Tripname":"whaynle"}]

System.out.println("--RESULT--" + result);
            JSONObject jObject = null;
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(result);

                //JSONArray a = jObject.getJSONArray("Tripname");


                String status = jObject.getString("Tripname");
                //Log.v("result1", jObject.toString());
                Log.v("Response", status);

            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: so you were able to retrive the `json` but can't parse it? Is that it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do like this**

```
JSONArray jArray= null;
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jObject= jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String status = jObject.getString("Tripname");
                //Log.v("result1", jObject.toString());
                Log.v("Response", status);
            }

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
try{
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
     JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String data1 = object.getString("0");
     String trip_name = object.getString("Tripname");
     Log.i("TripName",trip_name);
     //rest of the strings..
    }
 catch (JSONException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```